# am_proc_died : [23031,com.android.browser,9] automatically Browser app get closed

Tags: android

At that instances browser using 45753 KB of memory. For me it looks problem with OOM. Could you please conform about this and please let me know what is the significance of paramerter int of am_proc_died: [PID,Package Name, int]

45753 kB: Foreground
45753 kB: com.android.browser (pid 23031)